# What's the equivalent of System.out.println() in C#/Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, console

I am developing some projects in C# and Silverlight.

I am trying to print lines of code in order to debug, but `Console.Write()` doesn't seem to work.

I've created a Silverlight Application, not a Console Application where `Console.Write()` did work. How can I print in a console or in the output window in a Silverlight Application project?

Comment: Note: `System.out.println()` should not be used for debug or diagnostic messages. Use `System.err.println()` instead, or a real logger.

Answer (score 33):

Use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write` to print in the debug output window.

See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.write.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54ffa64k.aspx)

Comment: It is `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine`

Comment: both `Write` and `WriteLine` are valid

Comment: I'm noob .net trying to learn and came across this thread. For others who don't already know.... looking at my console output in vs2013,  System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write prints wherever and System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine prints on a line by itself.

Answer (score 4):

Using `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine();` like Fox32 and VoodooChild mentioned did not work for me initially. Apparently my debugging wasn't working at all (breakpoints did not hit for example).

I was able to fix the debugging by using IE instead of FireFox (see [Debugging Silverlight not hitting breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4556947/1145023))

As soon as that was fixed, the `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine();` worked perfectly :)