# Where are my writeline messages?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm new to Visual Studio C# and I've created my first DLL. I'm referencing this DLL within a web application.  In my code throughout numerous classes within the DLL and even in the controller classes of my web application, I make use of Console.WriteLine(...) to help with troubleshooting.  I fully expected those messages to be output to the console at runtime, but they aren't showing up. 
For example here is some code from a class that is attempting to access a MySQL database, and before I execute the query, I attempt to write the query string to the console:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = null;
MySqlDataReader rdr = null;
MySqlCommand cmd2 = null;         
try{
        Console.WriteLine("query: " + query.ToString());
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(query.ToString(), conn);
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
        ...
}
```

In Visual Studio, during project execution time, I've looked at the Immediate Window, the Output, Locals, Call Stack windows.

Where are my writeline messages?

Comment: If you use System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(...) instead of Console.WriteLine(), then you can see the results in the Output window of Visual Studio.

Comment: Well, I've replaced my Console.WriteLine with System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine where I had them, but my messages still aren't showing up in the Output window!  Is there something I'm missing?  I am in Debug mode.

Comment: What kind of web application is it, ASP.NET? Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000507/why-does-system-diagnostics-debug-writeline-not-work-in-vs2010-c-sharp

Comment: It's an MVC 3 project.

Comment: Then this seems to be the best duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668521/how-to-use-console-writeline-in-asp-net-mvc-3

Comment: I found the problem.  From the post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000507/why-does-system-diagnostics-debug-writeline-not-work-in-vs2010-c-sharp

Comment: That was the link from my second to last comment. Glad to hear that it works