# DotNet Core calling method via onscreen button

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, devextreme

In my DotNet Core application, I have a button set up with the some javascript placed in for my `OnClick` event. It looks like this:

```
<div>
    @(Html.DevExtreme().Button()
                             .Text("Press me")
                             .Type(ButtonType.Normal)
                             .Width(90)
                             .OnClick("notify")
    )
</div>

<script>
     function notify() {
        console.log("pressed");

       // ModifiedDuration.AdjustmentScreen_Netting.Csharp.RunBatch();
      //  var a = '<%=RunBatch()%>';
    }
</script>
```

The commented out lines are what I've tried to call my target method but neither have worked. The underlying method I want to call is this:

```
public void RunBatch()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Re-running batch");
    TestOutput print= new TestOutput ();
    print.TestMethod();
 }
```

Then, what `TestMethod` does:

```
public void ProcessAdjustedBatch()
{
    Console.WriteLine("I have been called from the datagrid!!!!");
}
```

So after I press the button, I would expect to see the following log messages:

- Pressed
- re-running batch
- I have been called from the datagrid!!!!

But all that I see is `Pressed` in my dev log. How can I achieve my intended output?

Comment: `function notify()` is evaluated at the client side, but I assume the `public void RunBatch()` is part of your backend. Therefore the browser can't use the function `RunBatch`. You could Expose an HTTP Interface for this method and invoe it over HTTP

Comment: These are two dofferent parts. First one is writing to browser log and the second one is writing to Console. You are mixing up client and server.

Answer (score 0):

`Console.WriteLine()` will never shown in client's browser because it runs server-side and opened in server's console window. It is necessary to use [`Debug.WriteLine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline?view=netframework-4.7.2) if you want to see debug messages in immediate output window.

Also note that `var a = '<%=RunBatch()%>'` only executes inside ASPX pages, it cannot be executed in Razor which uses `@{ ... }` for code segment, and both debug methods are server-side methods.

If you want to show server-side debug message in browser's console with `console.log()`, you need to create a controller action that executes both methods which have `string` return type and then use AJAX inside `notify()` function which outputs the result in `success` part.

Here is a simple example:

**Controller Action**

```
public IActionResult GetMessages()
{
    var messages = new StringBuilder();

    messages.Append(RunBatch());
    messages.Append("\n"); // use newline to separate messages from different methods
    messages.Append(ProcessAdjustedBatch());

    return Json(messages.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Debug Methods**

```
public static string RunBatch()
{
    string batch = "Re-running batch";
    Debug.WriteLine(batch);

    TestOutput print = new TestOutput();
    print.TestMethod();

    return batch;
}

public static string ProcessAdjustedBatch()
{
    return "I have been called from the datagrid!!!!";
}
```

**View (script tag)**

```
<script>
function notify() {
   console.log("pressed");

   $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: '@Url.Action("GetMessages", "ControllerName")',
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function (result) {
           console.log(result);
       }
   });
}
</script>
```

Now the console output should be like this:

```
pressed
Re-running batch
I have been called from the datagrid!!!!
```

Live example: [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qgY3gg)

Related issues:

[Where does Console.WriteLine go in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137660/where-does-console-writeline-go-in-asp-net)

[Asp.net mvc Console.WriteLine to browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713782/asp-net-mvc-console-writeline-to-browser)

[How to use Console.WriteLine in ASP.Net MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668521/how-to-use-console-writeline-in-asp-net-mvc-3)